# Sudden error "We are unable to connect to the VM on port 22" without any cause

Tags: ubuntu, google-compute-engine

I have `Angular`, `NodeJS` and `nginx` running on 2 core 8GB RAM ubuntu 18.04 instance on `google compute engine`. The server was operating normally (HDD 49%, CPU below 10% and RAM below 40%) but suddenly web frontend was not working (like server was stopped). At that time, I checked google cloud console and the system was working normally. Then I tried to `ssh` using `WinSCP` but couldn't connect to the host. Then I tried with web ssh on cloud console website, it neither. I restarted the server then everything was normal .

I checked all logs for my database and node server, server has been running entire time with no issue. I concluded that the OS was working the entire time.

I used monitoring on google console, the cpu was running but **no** network activity for the above period(incoming/outgoing)

1. Any explanation for above scenario? Should I troubleshoot it with server or issue from google?
2. What steps i can follow to identify problems in above scenarios? Which logs should I check?
3. In addition, any logs from google console that I can check for troubleshooting?

Answer (score 0):

For the description of your issue, I can only think that the google agent restarted the network services and, for some reason, it failed to start them properly.
Normally this can only be confirmed inside the OS by checking that the agent is running or checking the agent logs, however normally there is a generic message in Stackdriver logging that says “OS agent configuration started”. When the instance was restarted the agent started the configuration again.

Comment: No. Couldn't find any clue. First log after long time is shutting down it by myself

Comment: In that case there is a possibility that the Network Manager service has overwritten some configuration files, that depends of your OS but you could check that if you go to your network configuration files, normally network manager adds a comment like "Managed by Network Manager", however if it is working, maybe that message change for "Managed by google agent"

Answer (score 0):

As [@AdolfoOG](https://serverfault.com/users/532795/adolfoog) mentioned - you have to check the logs in order to troubleshoot this.

But when it happened you couldn't SSH into your machine. Even if you can't you can still check the [serial console output](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/viewing-serial-port-output) via console gui or `gcloud compute instances get-serial-port-output instance_name --zone=my_zone` command in Cloud Shell.

To be able to log in [enable interaction with serial console][4] `gcloud compute instances add-metadata instance-name --metadata serial-port-enable=TRUE` and connect to it with `gcloud compute connect-to-serial-port instance-name`.

Now when you're logged in you can check all the logs or services when the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

At first, you should **collect logs**:

1. Go to `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on NAME_OF_YOUR_VM -> at the `VM instance details` find section **Logs** and click on `Serial port 1 (console)`
2. Reboot your VM instance again.
3. Check full boot log for any errors or/and warnings.

**If you found errors/warning related to disk space** you can try to resize it accordingly to the documentation [Resizing a zonal persistent disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#resize_pd), also accordingly to the article [Recovering an inaccessible instance or a full boot disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#inaccessible_instance):

> If an instance is completely out of disk space or if it is not running
> a Linux guest environment, then automatically resizing your root
> filesystem isn't possible, even after you've increased the size of the
> persistent disk that backs it. If you can't connect to your instance,
> or your boot disk is full and you can't resize it, you must create a
> new instance and recreate the boot disk from a snapshot to resize it.

Otherwise try to **troubleshoot your VM instance via serial console**:

1. [Enable serial console connection](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#enable_instance_access) with `gcloud` command:

   ```
    gcloud compute instances add-metadata NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE \
    --metadata serial-port-enable=TRUE
   ```

or go to `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on `NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE` -> click on `EDIT` -> go to section **`Remote access`** and check `Enable connecting to serial ports`

2. Create temporary user and password to login: shutdown your VM and set a [startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) by adding at the section **`Custom metadata`** key `startup-script` and value:

   ```
    #!/bin/bash
    useradd --groups google_sudoers tempuser
    echo "tempuser:password" | chpasswd
   ```

and then start your VM.

3. [Connect to your VM via serial port](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#connectserialconsole) with `gcloud` command:

   ```
    gcloud compute connect-to-serial-port NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE
   ```

   or go to `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on `NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE` -> and click on `Connect to serial console`
4. Check what went wrong.
5. [Disable access via serial port](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#disable_access) with `gcloud` command:

   ```
    gcloud compute instances add-metadata NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE \
    --metadata serial-port-enable=FALSE
   ```

or go to `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on `NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE` -> click on `EDIT` -> go to section **`Remote access`** and uncheck `Enable connecting to serial ports`. Keep in mind that accordingly  to the documentation [Interacting with the serial console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console):

> **Caution**: The interactive serial console does not support IP-based access
> restrictions such as IP whitelists. If you enable the interactive
> serial console on an instance, clients can attempt to connect to that
> instance from any IP address. Anybody can connect to that instance if
> they know the correct SSH key, username, project ID, zone, and
> instance name. Use firewall rules to control access to your network
> and specific ports.

**If you weren't able to connect via serial console**, try follow the documentation [Troubleshooting SSH](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh) section [Inspect the VM instance without shutting it down](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh#inspect_vm) and **inspect the disk of your VM on another VM**. Same way you can transfer your data to another working VM instance.